# Need to access the other winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms : **Form1**, **Form2**.
Form1 has checkedlistbox : **checkedlistbox1**

All i need is when i click a button from Form2 then  checkedlistbox item should be clear.
From searching i found and applied this code but didn't work.

```
using (Form1 form1 = new Form1())
      {
          form1.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
      }
```

but didn't work.
Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Please go back and mark some answers as accepted on your old questions.

Comment: Do you already have an instance of form1 open, the code you have works on a different instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you do

```
using (Form1 form1 = new Form1())
```

you are actually creating a **new** instance of `Form1`. That's why it won't work. You need to get the current instance of `Form1`.

```
foreach (var item in Application.OpenForms)
{
    Form1 form1 = item as Form1;
    if (form1 != null)
    {
        form1.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

or probably

```
((Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"]).checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new form, that you don't show, and are clearing the list box on that form. What you need is a reference to the form you already have opened up. So wherever you open up `Form1` (from program.cs maybe?), store the reference to Form1 so that you can use that reference from `form2` so call `checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: Currently, in your program.cs file, it will say something like: `Form1 form = new Form1(); Application.Run(form);`. Create a new static public property called `MainForm` and change the code to `MainForm = new Form1(); Application.Run(MainForm);`. Then you can access it as a normal static property inside `Form2`.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is creating a new instance of the Form1. You need to access the one that is already created (having the list filled up) then do the clear.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the instance of Form1 to Form2, if you want to access that on the currently displayed form.
If you are displaying Form2 from within Form1 in the following fashion,

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();            
  form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

Then, you can use,

```
using (Form1 form1 = ((Form1)Owner))
  {
    form1.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing you should do:

- Make sure that the access modifier of form1 is public
- Register to the button `OnClick` event on form2
- Get a reference of Form1 from Form2, let's call it form1reference
- On click event you should write: `form1reference.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: I have already made checkedListBox1 public but still that doesn't work.

Comment: He is creating a new instance of the Form, that's why it is not working. Not the fact that it's not Public

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of Form1 here it will not work. Use property like Owner etc. Try something like this.

```
var myowner = this.Owner as Form1;
myowner.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

check or change the modifiers property of your checkbox of Form1 to public

Answer (score 0):

in the form 1 set check box 1 modifiers to public and if form1 is already opened
form2 code will be:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.checkBox1.Checked = false;

    }
```

Comment: He don't want to open Form1 from Form2. Both are open at the same time, and he wants to uncheck something in Form1 when clicking something else in Form2.

Answer (score 0):

Make your CheckBoxList public from `Form1.Designer.cs`.

Then

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();   
    //form1.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(0, true);
    form1.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear(); 
}
```