# c# creating reference between 2 forms

Tags: c#

My question may sound weird,but I have no idea on how to *create* a reference between 2 windows forms(for example to create a referrence and call it TheMainForm1).I'm fighting with this since 2 days(yes I know...) What I'm trying to do is to hide the Form1,but until now the only method I found is:

```
this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
```

But the above code creates a new Form1...

Please guide me on how to create a reference,I'm trying to learn c#.

HUGE thanks for any replay!

Comment: Tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184665/need-to-access-the-other-winform-in-c-sharp/11184761#11184761)? Just suggesting

Comment: Specify _reference between two windows_. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't see any method create new instance of Form1. So what exactly does you want?

Comment: I'm trying to acheav this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526902/c-sharp-winforms-application-showing-many-tray-icons/11526946#11526946

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass it in in the constructor for Form1 and store it in a member variable?

```
public Form1(Form2 form2)
{
  // store in member
  _form2 = form2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

There should be a `Program.cs` which contains a `Program` class. Add two static properties (or fields) and use them.

```
static class Program
{
    internal static Form1 form1;
    internal static Form2 form2;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form1 = new Form1();
        form2 = new Form2();
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
}
```

And if you want to switch from `Form1` to `Form2`, you can use this:

```
this.Hide();
Program.form2.Show();
```